# How to align subgraph to the bottom of another subgraph?

Tags: graphviz

graph is built by Graphviz:

```
graph {
    layout=circo;
    subgraph cluster_0 {
        1 -- { 2 3 4 5 6 }
        2 -- { 3 4 5 6 }
        3 -- { 4 5 6 }
        4 -- { 5 6 }
        5 -- { 6 }
    };

    subgraph cluster_1 {
        a -- b;
        a -- c;
        a -- d;
        1 -- a;
    };
}
```

[image]

How to align cluster_1 to the bottom of cluster_0?

Comment: Do you want "a" to line up with "6", "d" to line up with "6", or am I completely missing the mark?

Comment: @sroush yes I need to place star graph to the bottom of clique graph

Comment: You are using the circo layout engine.  Circo doesn't have any notion of "rank" or "clusters".  (remove all the cluster/subgraph notation and you will get the same result).  I can find no way to make circo work vertically instead of horizontally.